# major sins and lowering the gaze whitout lust and desire

Tags: backbiting

If i commit a major sin accidently do i have to repent? For example if i show my awrah when taking off my shirt am i sinful or  what if i did a major sin that i did not know was a sin? If i backbite someone out of forgetfulness do i have to repent? What if someone i backbited said that it is okay if i backbite him out of forgetfulness do i still have to then repent? And is it haram to not lower my gaze if i donr look out of lust and desire? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

- Since uncovering our arwah was an accident, you will not receive a sin, no will the people who may have also accidentally looked - however your wudu have broken so you should redo it
- If you backbite someone out of forgetfulness, then you should still repent and ask for forgiveness however it might not be as a serious of a sin since you forgot, it really depends on what you said - if the person you backbited about did not care or even allowed it (for whatever reason), then it is not a sin because they allowed / gave permission for it
- If your looking at the opposite gender **without** lust or desire, then it is permissible e.g. if they are your colleague or you are doing work with them - if it turns into lust or desire you should look away

Comment: Thanks you!!!!!